# pandas read_csv() method supports zip archive reading but not to_csv() method supports zip archive saving

Tags: python, csv, pandas, zip

Pandas 0.18 supports read_csv zip file as argument and reading zipped csv table correctly into data frame. But when i am trying to use to_csv() method to save data frame as zipped csv, i am getting error. According to official documentation, zip format not supported in to_csv() method. Any thoughts? Thank you.

import pandas as pd

works fine

data = pd.read_csv("E:\ASML SED.zip")

error out
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\ASML SED.zip'

data.to_csv("E:\ASML SED Zipped.zip", compression = 'zip')

Comment: I'm confused, the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv) says that `to_csv` supports gzip through the `compression` attribute. Why do you say it's not supported? Also some sample code would be helpful.

Comment: To_csv() doesnt support zip, while read_csv() does. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: added code example

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, zip format not supported in to_csv() method according to this [official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), the allowed values are ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘xz’.

If you really want the 'zip' format, you can try to save as uncompressed csv file, then using cli to compress the .csv file to .csv.zip.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide reference to cli?

Comment: @Felix you can use the commands in this page http://stahlworks.com/dev/?tool=zipunzip

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to compress my csv to zip and this really worked for me. U can adapt it to your code

```
import zipfile
import tempfile
file_name = "Your_csv_file_name.csv"
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix='.csv') as tempName:
            df.to_csv(tempName.name)
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,suffix=".zip") as tempZip:
                with zipfile.ZipFile(tempZip, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
                    zip_file.write(tempName.name, file_name)
```