# Saving a pandas dataframe to a csv inside a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zip

I am trying to save a data frame from pandas to a CSV file inside a zip archive. I looked up in pandas documentation and it seems that there is support for zip compression, but it does not work as expected. The code below saves a zip file

`df_test.to_csv(path_filtered_zips + '{}.zip'.format(name_of_the_file), compression='zip', index=False)`

Inside the zip file is the path from my partition to where the zip file is itself. See below the attached picture:

[image]

I managed to save it somewhat properly if I change the file type to ".gz" and compression to gzip. This creates the gz archive and inside a document with no formatting that can actually be opened and it is the data frame that I expected. You can see here:

[image]
The problem is that I need the archive to be of zipping type/compression and the file inside to be a CSV file format as I intend to use for other purposes.

The code I use to produce those results is the following:

```
for zip_file in list_of_zip_file:
    counter += 1
    full_name = zip_file.split(".")
    name_of_the_file = full_name[0]
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(path_zip_files + '/' + zip_file, "r")
    column_names = ['ip', 'date', 'cik', 'accession']
    df_test = pd.read_csv(archive.open(str(name_of_the_file) + ".csv"), low_memory=False, usecols=column_names)
    df_test = pd.merge(df_test, df_form, how='inner', on=['accession'])

    # The next line is where I changed the ".gz" and the compression to "zip" and get the mentioned errors. 
    df_test.to_csv(path_filtered_zips + '{}.gz'.format(name_of_the_file), compression='gzip', index=False)
    print(df_test)
    if counter == 1:
        break
```

Comment: `df_test.to_csv(path_filtered_zips + '{}.csv.gz'.format(name_of_the_file), compression='gzip', index=False)` working?

Comment: @anky_91 unfortunately no. Now I get the same error as when I did: `df_test.to_csv(path_filtered_zips + '{}.zip'.format(name_of_the_file), compression='zip', index=False)` Also, I need the file to be zip compression not gzip, but when I do the code above I get the weird error that is shown in the first picture.

Comment: Maybe I answered this kind of question here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838026/pandas-read-csv-method-supports-zip-archive-reading-but-not-to-csv-method-su/71943718#71943718>