# Download zipped csv file from server link and read into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I have been trying to download a zipped csv using the requests library from a server host URL.

When I download a smaller file not requiring compression from the same server it has no problem reading in the CSV, but with this one I return encoding errors.

I have tried multiple types of encoding, reading in as pandas csv, reading in as zip file and opening (at which point I get the error that file is not a zip file).

I have additionally tried using the zipfile library as sugggested here: [Reading csv zipped files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942476/reading-csv-zipped-files-in-python)

and have also tried setting both encoding and compression in `read_csv`.

The code which works for the non-zipped server file is below:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(un, pw), stream=True, verify = False)
dfs = pd.read_csv(response.raw)
```

but returns `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: invalid start byte` when used for this file.

I have also tried:

```
request = get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(un, pw), stream=True, verify=False)
zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(request.content))
files = zip_file.namelist()
with gzip.open(files[0], 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(row)
```

which returns a seek attribute error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838026/pandas-read-csv-method-supports-zip-archive-reading-but-not-to-csv-method-su/71943718#71943718 This answer up here, helped me, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zipfile import ZipFile
import io

# Example dataset
url = 'https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Retail-trade-survey/Retail-trade-survey-September-2020-quarter/Download-data/retail-trade-survey-september-2020-quarter-csv.zip'

response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(un, pw), stream=True, verify=False)
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as myzip:
    with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as myfile:
        df = pd.read_csv(myfile)

print(df)
```

If you want to read a specific csv in a multiple-csv zip file, replace `myzip.namelist()[0]` with the file you want to read. If you don't know its name, you can check the `zip` file content with `print(ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)))`

Comment: Thanks for this! So I tried this guy, but I get BadZipFile: File is not a zip file. The url extension does not say zip nor csv, just indicates that it is a servlet link

Comment: can you share the link or at least something similar to it?

Comment: something along the lines of https://server.data.com/ReportServer-1/FileDownloadServlet?reportId=1234567 
Not a real URL obviously but basically the exact structure - as you can see no file or folder extensions

Comment: does the file start downloading automatically when you click on the url? In either case, one way to do this is to scrape the page and look for the .zip file then use that as the `url`.

Comment: It does; I tried that and there's nothing on the page with any sort of file extension attribute

Comment: try and add a request header `headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}` then
`requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(un, pw), stream=True, verify=False, headers=headers)`

Comment: sorry - read some documentation but not certain how 1) this helps and 2) what headers i should be passing